# Is there an event like "OnAfterCompileHead"?

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, joomla-api, system-plugin, plugin-events

As per title, is there already an event that can work like a sort of `OnAfterCompileHead`?

Maybe `onAfterDispatch`, `onAfterRender` or `onBeforeRender`?

I need to change some meta tags in the `<head>` like `canonical`, `title`, and so on.

Comment: are you using any plugin for canonical urls??

Comment: @Joomler Nope, I'm trying to do some custom edits myself to `canonical` via custom plugin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have to edit my answer, as I think I didn't get right what you are actually want initially.

With all the 3 events you can do changes on the head. If you have other plugins that do the same, then you can re-order them.

- onAfterDispatch
- onBeforeRender
- onBeforeCompileHead

#### To edit the `<head>` data:

The head is stored in the document object and you can access it and manipulate it easily:

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();

$doc->setTitle('My Title');
$doc->setMetaData( 'tagname', 'tag content' );
$doc->addCustomTag( '<!-- this is a comment -->');
```

Examples:

```
$doc->setMetaData( 'description', 'My Description' );
$doc->addCustomTag( '<meta property="og:title" content="Custom og Title tag">');
```

You can also get the full head data with :

```
$head = $doc->getHeadData();
// echo '<pre>' . print_r($head, true) . '</pre>';
```

The `$head` is the array of data destined for the **`HTML <head>`** section in array form.
This only returns the data added by the set Methods of the JDoc. It will not return data about files that have been linked directly from html in the template head.

You can then set data to the `$head` like:

```
$head['metaTags']['standard']['keywords'] = 'keyword1, keyword2,...';

$doc->setHeadData($head);
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer, the `setHeadData` will do the trick! My question was mainly caused by my debugging tool which is Kint. Using Kint in the script I have (which is included at the bottom of the `<head>` tag) I think is causing the break of the `head` element and so returning empty values with all my tempted tests to retrieve data from the `head`. Looking with FFDev Tools I can see all meta tags shifted in the `<body>` and the `head` is totally emptied. I need to find a proper way to dump/log the data I need to see without breaking the whole output.